# Facebook Linter return a 200 error code

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to share to Facebook this url: 
http://curation.masternewmedia.org/ 
or an other url of this domain: 
http://curation.masternewmedia.org/p/1689258249/how-to-check-and-verify-news-info-in-real-time-from-social-media.

Facebook linter generates a 200 status code and *Could not retrieve data from URL*: 
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fcuration.masternewmedia.org%2F

When I curl the same url everything seems to be ok

```
$>> curl -I http://curation.masternewmedia.org/    

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 02 May 2012 08:53:29 GMT
Server: Jetty(7.5.4.v20111024)
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Language: en
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Set-Cookie: userId=e26ee613-8792-4f03-9066-52b6aa09a901;Path=/;Expires=Sat, 30-Apr-2022 08:53:31 GMT
Via: 1.1 www.scoop.it
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

Can you please help me to understand how I can fix this issue?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what the linter shows now:

> **Errors That Must Be Fixed**
>    Object **Type** Not Allowed At URL: Object at URL 'http://curation.masternewmedia.org/' of type 'scoop_it:topic' is invalid because the domain 'curation.masternewmedia.org' is not allowed for the application id '165307520164712' which owns the specified object type. If you are the owner of this application, you can verify your configured 'Site Domain' at https://developers.facebook.com/apps/165307520164712.

The other url http://curation.masternewmedia.org/p/1686490068/four-great-curators-to-draw-inspiration-from shows that the `og:type` is `scoop_it:article` , and that works fine, so i guess you should be changing to `scoop_it:article`.

If you are using scoop.it's service then let them know of this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be that the Facebook scraper is seeing nothing *at all* in the source code of your site. [This link](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http://curation.masternewmedia.org/) will give you a view of what the scraper sees when it visits your site

I'm no expert, but I have a feeling there's something wrong with the object you've specified in the "type" section, i.e. topic

```
<meta property="og:type" content="topic"/>
```

Removing this made it work for me. If you have defined a custom action type and are using that, but have not yet had it approved, it might be caused by that. Anyway, it seems to be boiling down to that part.

You can see it working with the url soccerrumors.mobi/test/test.html

Comment: What about this url where evrything seems to be ok and Facebook answer is the same ? https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fcuration.masternewmedia.org%2Fp%2F1686490068%2Ffour-great-curators-to-draw-inspiration-from